# California being more powerful than the federal government

Tags: california

The federal government has the power of administrative wage garnishment. This allows it to complete a levy by filling  a form rather than filing a collection lawsuit and using courts. It is still an administrative procedure, there is still a form to issue.

The California Franchise Tax Board bypasses this entirely. It is mechanistically able to levy my chase bank account for $3000 just by calling chase and never even mailing a physical judgement.

Under procedural behavior, California has more power to levy bank accounts than the federal government does, it doesn't even need an administrative process to do it. This is probably unconstitutional as California can "get levies out" faster than the federal government and "win" the race to get funds first.

Does this violate the Supremacy Clause?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question. Law Stack Exchange is not a place for commentary.

Comment: It is a question if it violates the supremacy clause

Answer (score 1):

Your premise that California's tax collection powers are greater than federal tax collection powers is basically wrong.

Both California and the federal government carry out most of their due process functions within their respective tax collection agencies in an administrative process rather than in the courts. In the federal system, the courts are usually resorted to only when that taxpayer pays the taxes due and then seeks a refund, or when their is an appeal from the final layer of the IRS administrative law system which is the Article I court known as Tax Court (in which I have litigated more than once).

The Supremacy Clause is only violated when a state law violates or contradicts a federal law, which is not what happens in this case. The federal government can and has set up a system for determining whether the federal or state tax collection rights have priority in the same asset, which mostly flows from the timing of the recording of a tax lien by the relevant bodies.

Comment: They actually had a severe problem because although there were no federal levies to compete with, chase levied a $100 legal fee before collecting the judgment. California perceives the legal fee as stealing from California and is angry at Chase.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss Interesting but far beyond the scope of the question and the answer.

Comment: What if federal and state levies happened at the same time?

Comment: @DhdhUsuss https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-wd/0922049.pdf This is basically impossible. At a nuts and bolts level, the agencies that record federal and state tax liens process all tax lien filings sequentially, one at a time and assign filing numbers to each filing in order of filing. The tax collector with the earlier filing number wins, even if the filings are in the very same minute.

Comment: It seems that doesn't apply to private bank fees. Chase was able to steal $100 from California.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss The fee that Chase charges California has nothing to do with the relative priority of U.S. and California tax liens. If Chase is in the wrong, California is more than capable of litigating that issue with it and prevailing.

Comment: The ftb is in chaos as this is the first time this has ever happened. It released the levy. The levy was for 3000. Chase took 100 and still has it. California attempted the remaining 2900, then withdrew and I took 2900 out and closed the account. Ftb is unable to respond to communications or function at the moment.

Comment: See also re priorities: https://www.ftb.ca.gov/pay/collections/withholding-orders/collection-hierarchy.html I found no evidence of a dispute between Chase and the CA FTB but ask another question and support it with a link if you have a question about that legality of that.

Comment: Problem is this isn't a collection, it's a arbitrary bank fee. There is no policy there.

Comment: Also my question button is broken.

Comment: @DhdhUsuss Unless otherwise regulated by law, banks are allowed to charge arbitrary fees if they put the fees in their contacts.

Comment: It's not in any kind of contract so I assume chase is a failure.